# event.preventDefault(); does not work like I expect

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to validate my form when 'Submit' button is clicked on this form before the page is submitted.

The validate function is called and executed as expected; but the form is not submitted afterwards, leaving the changes unsaved.

Here is part of the code -

```
$j("#btnSubmit").on("click",function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            alert("validation complete");
            return;
}); 

<button type="submit"  name="btnSubmit" id="btnSubmit"  value="btnSubmit"> </button>
```

Comment: So you prevent the default submission, so when you validate and it passes, do you then submit the form, return something, or do nothing?

Comment: How do **you** expect [`preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) to work?

Comment: @angelcool.net - preventDefault is being called -- what would returning true do?

Comment: guess you got the concept of `event.preventDefault();` totally wrong :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

event.preventDefault(); stops the execution. Give an `id` to your form and add `$('#formid').submit();` instead of your `return`.

Edit:

Change your button type to button instead of submit, so that the form is submitted only after your validation.

Comment: That will just trigger the original `submit` event, causing a massive loop.

Answer (score 1):

You're cancelling the submit event with `event.preventDefault()`, so now you need to manually handle the submit after your validation instead of just doing `return`.

You can then use something like AJAX to do the actual submission. Refer to Keerthi's method for a non AJAX way of submitting the form.

Please bear in mind if you do `$('#myForm').submit()` or something similar it'll just run your original function to validate and cause a loop.

Answer (score 1):

You will want to look into the `$().submit()` function.

If you `preventDefault()` you stop the click even from propagating, so the submit will definitely not fire. What you will want to do is either capture the submit event

`$('#myForm').submit(function(){ validate(); return; })`

or youll want to manually call the submit in your click handler

```
$("#btnSubmit").on("click",function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    alert("validation complete");
    $('#myForm).submit();
});
```